# JavaScript - Project Euler #5 -- efficiency

Tags: javascript, math

This is for Project Euler, problem #5.

The task is to find the smallest number evenly divisible by numbers 1-20. My code seems to work on 1-18, but at 19 my browser starts timing out. This leads me to believe my code is just inefficient.

How can I mitigate this?

```
function divisible(a){
    counter = 0;
    result = 2;
    while (counter < a){
        for (var x = 0; x <= a; x ++){
            if (result % x === 0){
                counter ++;
            }
        }
        if (counter != a){
            counter = 0;
            result ++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
divisible(20)
```

Comment: There is a mathematical reason for the inefficiency but this has nothing to do with JavaScript nor code

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that I'm just manually dividing each iteration?

Comment: Well, for starters, you're wasting an awful lot of time checking numbers even after you know they're not going to pass. The first time `result % x !== 0`, you already know it's not the answer, but you keep testing the rest of the numbers. For another, you're testing divisibility by 0, which always returns `NaN`, so you should probably start the testing with a legal divisor. Finally, you're testing stuff you don't need to test; you know the result must be divisible by 16 (for example), which means you don't need to test 1, 2, 4, or 8, since divisibility by 16 naturally encompasses the others.

Comment: Thanks! I was already on the cusp of the second bit, but I was having a lot of trouble translating that into my loop. I guess that's where I need to focus for now, though.

Comment: Well, there are far better solutions than what I'm suggesting; I'm only giving you ways to reduce wasted computations on the naive solution, but the naive solution is still naive. A solution based on computing the product of the maximum prime factor powers of each intended divisor gets you the answer for the cost of factorizing 20 very small numbers, which is a lot cheaper than an iterative guess and check approach.
That said, for a problem this small, even a mildly optimized naive solution will solve it quickly. A later problem asks for an even larger number though; naive won't cut it there.

Comment: I was able to get the solution by cutting out most of the dividends, so there's that!

Comment: @Bairdley i hope this is the optimiert solution you have been looking for.      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898775/javascript-project-euler-5-efficiency/40122685#40122685

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of 1,...,20.

I would implement `lcm` by using [`gcd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor), which can be implemented using the fast [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

```js
function gcd(a, b) {
  return b === 0 ? a : gcd(b, a%b); // Euclidean algorithm
}
function lcm(a, b) {
  return a * b / gcd(a, b);
}
function divisible(a){
  var result = 1;
  for(var i=2; i<=a; ++i)
    result = lcm(result, i);
  return result;
}
divisible(20); // 232792560
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, inefficient. You would need to change the algorithm. The most efficient I can think of is to factorise all the numbers from 2 to 20 (with factors and counts: e.g. 18 is 3 * 3 * 2, or twice 3 and once 2, for final `{ 3: 2, 2: 1 }`); then find the maximum for each factor, and multiply them together.

An abbreviated example: the least number that is divisible by 18 and 16:

```
18: { 3: 2, 2: 1 }
16: { 2: 4 }

maximums of factor repetitions: { 3: 2, 2: 4 }
result: 3^2 * 2^4 = 144
```

Factorising numbers from 2 to 20 is easy; if you don't know how to do it, there are many possible algorithms, you can see [the Wikipedia article on integer factorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) for ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm definitely going to have to do a bit of studying to work out this type of solution, but I'm working on it!

Answer (score 1):

> another option with brute force and modulo rest-classification

this problem can be solved with a simple common modulo rest class characteristics.
look at the numbers from 1 to 20 and divide it into two groups and find some unique common attributes between them.

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
   we are building a division with the same reminder members
```

1 divides all

2 divide 4,8 -->>8 important

3 divide 6,9 but 6 doesnt divide 9 evenly--> 6,9

5 divide 10-->> 10 important

that leaves us with 6,7,8,9,10 to check if there is any number from 1 that can divide this with rest 0.

the trick is if 2,4,8 divides a number let say 16 with the same reminder then we don't have to check if 2,4 divides 16, we check only 8.

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

here we can do the same from about with factors of the numbers from above and we will be left with

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

> NB: we know that the last number that has to divide the number is 20,
>   so that means either the solution will be a number ending with 0 or is
>   one of the factors of 20, so we build factors of 20 and check if 11 12
>   13 14 15 16 17 18 19 can divide it then we are done.

```
int start = 20;

    while (start % 11 != 0 || start % 12 != 0 | start % 13 != 0 || start % 14 != 0 || 
            start % 15 != 0 || start % 16 != 0 || start % 17 != 0 || start % 18 != 0 || start % 19 != 0 )
    {
        start += 20;
    }
    console.log(start)
```

> The same idea applies analogue to the first deduction I made to make the
>   problem seems smaller.

//smallest number divisible by all numbers from 1 to 10

```
int a = 10;

    while (a % 6 != 0 || a % 7 != 0 | a % 8 != 0 || a % 9 != 0 )
    {
        a += 10;
    }

console.log(a)
```

//smallest number divisible by all numbers from 1 to 5

```
int i = 5;                          

    while (i % 3 != 0 || i % 4 != 0)
    {
        i += 5;
    }

console.log(i)
```