# Project Euler #5 efficiency and error

Tags: javascript

### The question from the site:

2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

---

### My question

I have a problem, concerning both efficiency and error in my code. I have studied and looked around at other answers when I couldn't get past through my way, but I still do not understand how this would be accomplished. Also, my code doesn't work apparently when I plug it in for the 2520 with 1-10.

**Please note** that I do **NOT** want the answer or solution concerning the efficiency, just an explanation of how I could accomplish it (*AKA a hint*). But for the error in my code, I would like a solution. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
var recentArray = [];
var fullArray = [];
var numberCheck = 20;

function makeNewNumbers(i1, i2) {

    for (var i = i1; i < i2; i++) {
        recentArray = [];
        for (var j = 2; j <= numberCheck; j++) {
            recentArray.push(i % j);
        }
        fullArray.push(recentArray);
    }
}

var counter = 0;
var iStart = 0,
    iLess = 1000;
var success = false;

var newCheck = setInterval(function () {
    while (counter < 10 && success === false) {
        counter++;
        makeNewNumbers(iStart, iLess);
        for (var o = 1; o < fullArray.length; o++) {
            recentFound = false;
            if (numberCheck === 20 && fullArray[o][0] === 0 && fullArray[o][1] === 0 && fullArray[o][2] === 0 && fullArray[o][3] === 0 && fullArray[o][4] === 0 && fullArray[o][5] === 0 && fullArray[o][6] === 0 && fullArray[o][7] === 0 && fullArray[o][8] === 0 && fullArray[o][9] === 0 && fullArray[o][10] === 0 && fullArray[o][11] === 0 && fullArray[o][12] === 0 && fullArray[o][13] === 0 && fullArray[o][14] === 0 && fullArray[o][15] === 0 && fullArray[o][16] === 0 && fullArray[o][17] === 0 && fullArray[o][18] === 0) {
                clearInterval(newCheck);
                console.log("Success!!! Number: " + o);
                success = true;
                break;
            } else if (numberCheck === 10 && fullArray[o][0] === 0 && fullArray[o][1] === 0 && fullArray[o][2] === 0 && fullArray[o][3] === 0 && fullArray[o][4] === 0 && fullArray[o][5] === 0 && fullArray[o][6] === 0 && fullArray[o][7] === 0 && fullArray[o][8] === 0) {
                clearInterval(newCheck);
                console.log("Success!!! Number: " + o);
                success = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    iStart += 1000;
    iLess += 1000;
    console.log("Not found...\nSearch is continued. To postpone type \'clearInterval(newCheck)\'\nNerd stats: --- Starting minimum: " + iStart + " --- Starting maximum: " + iLess);
}, 1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Project Euler #5 — efficiency](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32898775/1529630)

Comment: @Oriol There is note that the question is not about the efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs is the above algorithm:

The internal `counter` loop does not increase `iStart` and `iLess`. So the second iteration gives `1000th` array element with zero `i`. That is why it gives answer `1000`. `iStart` and `iLess` should be increased in that loop:

```
while (counter < 10 && success === false) {
    // ...
    iStart += 1000;
    iLess += 1000;
}
```

The variable `counter` is not reset to zero after the full cycle run. So, the maximum probed number is `9999`. After the `while` loop `counter` should be set to zero.

---

Such algorithm is very inefficient. It is able to solve the problem for `10`. Probably it can be used for `15`. However, I do not expect to receive the result for `20` in a reasonable time.

More efficient and quite obvious algorithm may be based on counting prime factors of all numbers in given range (`1..20`). The maximum count of each unique prime factor for all numbers in range should be multiplied to give the result.
It can be done even better using Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Factorizing may be OK for 1,...,20 but will be very expensive for bigger numbers. The Euclidean algorithm is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

When tackling a problem like this simplify it with out loosing the essence of the problem. It will be easier to work through. For example solve this simpler problem:

12 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 4 without any remainder.

Do it with pen and paper and pseudo code first if necessary then code it.

Also check that there is no remainder when using the % remainder operator and keep a running count. You seem to be storing the results in an array which isn't necessary.

Also another tip - you ask that we do not comment on efficiency and yet it is in the title of the question.

As this is a Euler question even a brute force algorithm of incrementing by 20  and checking the other numbers in turn is so fast knowledge of Euclidean methods aren't necessary. It only requires an answer not an efficient method.

For larger numbers efficiency requirements and 'number overflow' checks all need to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Use math, not brute-force.

> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

Mathematically, this is called the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of 1, ..., 20.

A very fast way to calculate the least common multiple of two numbers is using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to calculate the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

```
function gcd(a, b) { // Greatest common divisor
  if(b == 0) return a;
  return gcd(b, a%b);
}
function lcm(a, b) { // Least common multiple
  return a * b / gcd(a, b);
}
var n = 1;
for(var i=1; i<=20; ++i) n = lcm(n, i);
n; // 232792560
```